# getting error ( Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function) when looping over a GRanges object

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have two dat sets: one as a GRanges object made by `GRangesList` with multiple subsets (grl) and another one (Test). I would like to loop over all subsets of `grl` and use function `findOverlaps` in "GenomicRanges"library to find their overlap with `Test` and save data (only one value after each iteration) in a list.

the output should look like:

```
gr1   2
gr2   5
gr3   1


gr1 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = "chr2", ranges = IRanges(3, 6),
          strand = "+", score = 5L, GC = 0.45)
gr2 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(7,13), width = 3),
          strand = c("+", "-"), score = 3:4, GC = c(0.3, 0.5))
gr3 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr2"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(1, 4), c(3, 9)),
          strand = c("-", "-"), score = c(6L, 2L), GC = c(0.4, 0.1))
grl <- GRangesList("gr1" = gr1, "gr2" = gr2, "gr3" = gr3)
grl


Test <-
    GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(1, 5), c(2, 6)),
          strand = c("-", "-"), score = c(6L, 2L), GC = c(0.5, 0.2))


myFunction <- function(input,feature){

    tmp = list()

        for (f in 1:length(objects(feature))){

            mtch = findOverlaps(currmySegm, eval(parse(text=paste0("feature$", objects(feature[f]), sep = "")))))
            **some calculations**
            value <- mean(...)  
            }
        temp[[objects(feature[f])]] <- value
}

myFunction(Test,grl)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function
```

I think there is either something wrong with `eval(parse(text=paste0("feature$", objects(feature[f]), sep = ""))))` which I can not pass the subsets of the `grl` to the function `findOverlaps` or saving the results as a list

Comment: `findOverlaps` works with both `GRanges` and `GRangesList` objects (see `?GenomicRanges::findOverlaps`). You can get all overlaps either by doing `findOverlaps(grl, Test)` or (maybe more explicitly) `lapply(grl, function(x) findOverlaps(x, Test))`; according to your sample data, only `gr3` overlaps with `Test`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks a lot. It helped me to solve the issue. mtch = lapply(grl, function(x) findOverlaps(x, Test)) worked. But if I wanted to do: myRanges = ranges(mtch,ranges(Test),lapply(grl, function(x) ranges(x))) it did nt work. when I replaced mtch with lapply(mtch, function(y ranges(y)), i mean like: myRanges = ranges(lapply(mtch, function(y ranges(y)),ranges(Test),lapply(grl, function(x) ranges(x)))  it did not work as well. would you please help me

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `ranges`. `mtch` will give you the hits (i.e. indices) of the overlapping `GRanges` entries. Do you want to count the number of overlapping features? Or extract the intersecting ranges?

Answer (score -1):

Different `findOverlaps` examples:

```
# GRangesList object
gr1 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = "chr2", ranges = IRanges(3, 6),
          strand = "+", score = 5L, GC = 0.45)
gr2 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(7,13), width = 3),
          strand = c("+", "-"), score = 3:4, GC = c(0.3, 0.5))
gr3 <-
  GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr2"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(1, 4), c(3, 9)),
          strand = c("-", "-"), score = c(6L, 2L), GC = c(0.4, 0.1))
grl <- GRangesList("gr1" = gr1, "gr2" = gr2, "gr3" = gr3)


# GRanges object
Test <-
    GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
          ranges = IRanges(c(1, 5), c(2, 6)),
          strand = c("-", "-"), score = c(6L, 2L), GC = c(0.5, 0.2))

# Get overlaps at the GRanges entry level of a GRangesList object
# This extracts the overlapping GRanges entries from your grl
# GRangesList object that overlap with a feature from Test.
hits1 <- lapply(grl, function(x) findOverlaps(x, Test));
grl.overlapping <- list();
for (i in 1:length(hits1)) { 
    grl.overlapping[[i]] <- grl[[i]][queryHits(hits1[[i]])];
}
names(grl.overlapping) <- names(grl);
print(grl.overlapping);

# Count the number of overlapping GRanges objects for every
# list entry from grl
counts <- lapply(hits1, length);
print(counts);

# Get overlaps at the GRangesList level
# Note this will only tell you whether *any* GRanges entries from your
# grl GRangesList object overlap with a feature from Test; it won't 
hits2 <- findOverlaps(grl, Test);
print(grl[queryHits(hits2)]);
```